# Python Soccer Betting Model, How To Only Use 6 Latest Matches?

Tags: python

Need some help to this Python Soccer betting model.
I have this working script as shown below.
Now the problem with this is that variable 'matchrating' should only be based on the 6 latest matches so it represents form. 
It's now off because at the end of the season the matchrating becomes very unrealistic as it uses all the matches played.

Can someone help me out?

The N1.csv used is from http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1617/N1.csv

```
import csv, math, ast, numpy as np

csvFile = 'N1.csv'

team_list = []

k = open ('team_list.txt', 'w')
k.write("""{
""")

csvRead = csv.reader(open(csvFile))
next(csvRead)

for row in csvRead:
    if row[2] not in team_list:
        team_list.append(row[2])
    if row[3] not in team_list:
        team_list.append(row[3])

team_list.sort()

for team in team_list:
    k.write(""" '%s': {'goals_for': 0, 'goals_against': 0, 'teamrating': 0},
""" % (team))

k.write("}")
k.close()

s = open('team_list.txt', 'r').read()
dict = ast.literal_eval(s)

GAMES_PLAYED = 0
WEEKS_WAIT = 4
TOTAL_VALUE = 0

starting_bankroll = 100
stake = 5
bankroll = starting_bankroll

matchrating_low = -3
matchrating_high = 3

bets = 0

csvRead = csv.reader(open(csvFile))
next(csvRead)

for game in csvRead:
    home_team = game[2]
    away_team = game[3]

    goals_for = int(game[4])
    goals_against = int(game[5])

    home_win_prob = 0
    draw_win_prob = 0
    away_win_prob = 0

    matchrating = 0

    team_bet = ''
    ev_bet = ''

    if (GAMES_PLAYED > (WEEKS_WAIT * 9)):
        home_teamrating = (dict[home_team]['goals_for'] - dict[home_team]['goals_against'])
        away_teamrating = (dict[away_team]['goals_for'] - dict[away_team]['goals_against'])
        matchrating = home_teamrating - away_teamrating

        home_win_prob = ((1.76 * matchrating) + 49.47) / 100
        draw_win_prob = (((-0.03 * (matchrating ** 2)) - (0.49 * matchrating)) + 21.48) / 100
        away_win_prob = (((0.03 * (matchrating ** 2)) - (1.47 * matchrating)) + 29.65) / 100

        home_odd = float(game[33])
        draw_odd = float(game[35])
        away_odd = float(game[37])

        implied_prob_home = 1 / home_odd
        implied_prob_draw = 1 / draw_odd
        implied_prob_away = 1 / away_odd

        home_ev = (((stake * home_odd) - stake) * home_win_prob) - (stake * (draw_win_prob + away_win_prob))
        draw_ev = (((stake * draw_odd) - stake) * draw_win_prob) - (stake * (home_win_prob + away_win_prob))
        away_ev = (((stake * away_odd) - stake) * away_win_prob) - (stake * (home_win_prob + draw_win_prob))

        highest_ev = max(home_ev, draw_ev, away_ev)

        if (home_ev == highest_ev) and (home_ev > 0) and (matchrating > matchrating_low) and (matchrating < matchrating_high):
            team_bet = home_team
            ev_bet = home_ev
            bets = bets + 1
            if goals_for > goals_against:
                bankroll += stake * (home_odd - 1)
            else:
                bankroll -= stake

        elif (draw_ev == highest_ev) and (draw_ev > 0) and (matchrating > matchrating_low) and (matchrating < matchrating_high):
            team_bet = 'Draw'
            ev_bet = draw_ev
            bets = bets + 1
            if goals_for == goals_against:
                bankroll += stake * (draw_odd - 1)
            else:
                bankroll -= stake

        elif (away_ev == highest_ev) and (away_ev > 0) and (matchrating > matchrating_low) and (matchrating < matchrating_high):
            team_bet = away_team
            ev_bet = away_ev
            bets = bets + 1
            if goals_for < goals_against:
                bankroll += stake * (away_odd - 1)
            else:
                bankroll -= stake

        print ("%s(%s) - %s(%s) = %s" % (home_team, home_teamrating, away_team, away_teamrating, matchrating))
        print ("Prob: %s | %s | %s" % (home_win_prob, draw_win_prob, away_win_prob))
        print ("Impl. Prob: %s | %s | %s" % (implied_prob_home, implied_prob_draw, implied_prob_away))
        print ("Odd: %s | %s | %s" % (home_odd, draw_odd, away_odd))
        print ("EV: %s | %s | %s >> %s" % (home_ev, draw_ev, away_ev, highest_ev))
        print ("Bankroll: %s" % (bankroll))
        print ("Games played: %s | Bets placed: %s" % (GAMES_PLAYED, bets))

    dict[home_team]['goals_for'] += goals_for
    dict[home_team]['goals_against'] += goals_against

    dict[away_team]['goals_for'] += goals_for
    dict[away_team]['goals_against'] += goals_for

    GAMES_PLAYED += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load the full csv file into a list in one step, which would make your code easier to follow in the first instance.

Then simply:

```
games = games_list[-6:]
```

will give you a shorter list with only the last 6 games, for onward processing.

EDIT:

After looking again I can see that the problem is more involved than I initially thought.

The Solution is to compile a **List** of the goals for and against each team as each game is processed.  Then the Rating can be calculated by **slicing** the last 6 Ratings from the list.

In keeping with my other comments, I've reworked your code a bit:

```
import csv

def read_csv(filename):
    _csv_data = []

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
        headers = next(csv_reader)
        for read_line in csv_reader:
            line_dict = {header:val for header, val in zip(headers, read_line)}
            _csv_data.append(line_dict)
    return _csv_data

def find_unique_teams(datafile):
    _team_list = []
    for record in datafile:
        if record['HomeTeam'] not in _team_list:
            _team_list.append(record['HomeTeam'])
        if record['AwayTeam'] not in _team_list:
            _team_list.append(record['AwayTeam'])
    _team_list.sort()
    return _team_list


csvFile = 'N1.csv'

#process CSV file
game_data = read_csv(csvFile)
#Extract Team list
team_list = find_unique_teams(game_data)
#Generate Form dictionary 
form_dict = {team_name : {'goals_for': [], 'goals_against': []} for team_name in team_list}

GAMES_PLAYED = 0
WEEKS_WAIT = 4
TOTAL_VALUE = 0

starting_bankroll = 100
stake = 5
bankroll = starting_bankroll

matchrating_low = -3
matchrating_high = 3

bets = 0

for game in game_data:
    home_team = game['HomeTeam']
    away_team = game['AwayTeam']

    goals_for = int(game['FTHG'])
    goals_against = int(game['FTAG'])

    home_win_prob = 0
    draw_win_prob = 0
    away_win_prob = 0

    matchrating = 0

    team_bet = ''
    ev_bet = ''

    if (GAMES_PLAYED > (WEEKS_WAIT * 9)):
        home_teamrating = (sum(form_dict[home_team]['goals_for'][-6:]) - sum(form_dict[home_team]['goals_against'][-6:]))
        away_teamrating = (sum(form_dict[away_team]['goals_for'][-6:]) - sum(form_dict[away_team]['goals_against'][-6:]))
        matchrating = home_teamrating - away_teamrating

        home_win_prob = ((1.76 * matchrating) + 49.47) / 100
        draw_win_prob = (((-0.03 * (matchrating ** 2)) - (0.49 * matchrating)) + 21.48) / 100
        away_win_prob = (((0.03 * (matchrating ** 2)) - (1.47 * matchrating)) + 29.65) / 100

        home_odd = float(game['BbAvH'])
        draw_odd = float(game['BbAvD'])
        away_odd = float(game['BbAvA'])

        implied_prob_home = 1 / home_odd
        implied_prob_draw = 1 / draw_odd
        implied_prob_away = 1 / away_odd

        home_ev = (((stake * home_odd) - stake) * home_win_prob) - (stake * (draw_win_prob + away_win_prob))
        draw_ev = (((stake * draw_odd) - stake) * draw_win_prob) - (stake * (home_win_prob + away_win_prob))
        away_ev = (((stake * away_odd) - stake) * away_win_prob) - (stake * (home_win_prob + draw_win_prob))

        highest_ev = max(home_ev, draw_ev, away_ev)

        if (home_ev == highest_ev) and (home_ev > 0) and (matchrating > matchrating_low) and (matchrating < matchrating_high):
            team_bet = home_team
            ev_bet = home_ev
            bets = bets + 1
            if goals_for > goals_against:
                bankroll += stake * (home_odd - 1)
            else:
                bankroll -= stake

        elif (draw_ev == highest_ev) and (draw_ev > 0) and (matchrating > matchrating_low) and (matchrating < matchrating_high):
            team_bet = 'Draw'
            ev_bet = draw_ev
            bets = bets + 1
            if goals_for == goals_against:
                bankroll += stake * (draw_odd - 1)
            else:
                bankroll -= stake

        elif (away_ev == highest_ev) and (away_ev > 0) and (matchrating > matchrating_low) and (matchrating < matchrating_high):
            team_bet = away_team
            ev_bet = away_ev
            bets = bets + 1
            if goals_for < goals_against:
                bankroll += stake * (away_odd - 1)
            else:
                bankroll -= stake

        print("{0:16s}({1:3d}) Vs {2:16s}({3:3d}) = {4:3d}".format(home_team, home_teamrating, away_team, away_teamrating, matchrating))
        print("Prob        : {0:8.4f} | {1:8.4f} | {2:8.4f}".format(home_win_prob, draw_win_prob, away_win_prob))
        print("Impl. Prob  : {0:8.4f} | {0:8.4f} | {0:8.4f}".format(implied_prob_home, implied_prob_draw, implied_prob_away))
        print("Odd         : {0:8.2f} | {1:8.2f} | {2:8.2f}".format(home_odd, draw_odd, away_odd))
        print("EV          : {0:8.4f} | {1:8.4f} | {2:8.4f} >> {3:8.4f}".format(home_ev, draw_ev, away_ev, highest_ev))
        print("Bankroll    : {0:6.2f}".format(bankroll))
        print("Games played: {0:8d} | Bets placed: {1:3d}".format(GAMES_PLAYED, bets))
        print()

    form_dict[home_team]['goals_for'].append(goals_for)
    form_dict[home_team]['goals_against'].append(goals_against)

    form_dict[away_team]['goals_for'].append(goals_for)
    form_dict[away_team]['goals_against'].append(goals_for)

    GAMES_PLAYED += 1
```

I've not checked the results, so hopefully it works.  Sorry if I've taken a liberty, I got carried away!

Comment: I'm not that good with Python, could you tell me how to exactly ?

Comment: I'll give it a try when I get home and let you know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works great! I was hoping for a different outcome but that's another thing ;)

Comment: @GerritSiegersma Please mark this as your accepted answer, if you're happy with it.  Glad I could help.